# Adding <form> tags around form disables Razor code from filling in input elements

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, forms

I am creating an edit form for an Event data model in which the input elements are populated with the Event properties for editing.  After I finished populating the fields and formatting the page, I realised I had forgotten the form tags.  After adding them in, my Razor code completely stops working, leaving all of the input elements empty.  I have tried disabling various parts of the code, including all javascript and css and nothing seems to re-populate the fields except removing the form tags.

Here is the code:

```
@model Objects.Models.Event.Event

@using EventSignup.Extensions

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.22.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Javascript/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Javascript/Edit.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<h2>Edit</h2>

<div class="hero-unit">
<form action="" id="event_form" method="post">
    <label for="name">Event Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="@Model.EventName" /><br />

    <label for="tickets"># of Tickets:</label>
    <input type="text" name="tickets" id="tickets" value="@Model.Tickets" /><br />

    <label for="location">Location:</label>
    <select name="location" id="location">        
        @foreach (var Element in ViewBag.Buildings as List<EventSignup.ViewModels.SelectElement>)
        {
            <option value="@Element.ID" @((Model.TicketsLocation.ID == @Element.ID) ? "selected='selected'" : "")>@Element.DisplayName</option>
        }
    </select><br />

    <label for="dates">Dates/Times:</label>
    @foreach (var EventInfo in Model.Dates)
    {
        <input type="text" class="date" name="dates" id="dates@(Model.Dates.IndexOf(EventInfo)+1)" value="@EventInfo.DateTime.ToDateTimePickerString()"/><br />
        if (EventInfo != Model.Dates.Last())
        {
            <label></label>
        }
    }
    <div id="date_inputs">
    </div>
    <label></label>
    <span id="new_date" class="fauxlink" onclick="newDate()">New Date/Time</span><br /><br />
    <input type="hidden" id="num_dates" value="@Model.Dates.Count" />

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /><br />
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe that `form action=""` shouldn't be blank

Comment: What would replace it?  I've always used action="" to post to the relevant action.

Comment: You should define `Controller/Action`

Comment: Is the generated markup valid with the `<form>` tags?

Comment: using `action="@Url.Action("Edit", "Event", new { id = Model.ID }, null)"` posts back the info properly but still keeps the input elements from being populated

Comment: @theyshookhands After all, could you find what was the problem at your form? Have you tested the complete `<form>` tag (the empty action, I mean)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use form elements directly - use the [`BeginForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform.aspx) HTML helper:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

}
```

You should also be using the template editors for the different model properties:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EventName)
```

---

Update:

I normally find that Visual Studio/Razor will stop working (no intellisense for instance) if the markup is not valid (missing `"` at the end of an attribute, elements that are not properly closed etc...). Check your markup carefully to see where your have such an error.

Comment: I've seen this kind of suggestion many times here at SO, but I've never seen someone justifying it. Could you kindly provide some reasons to support the use of HTML Helpers?

Comment: @AndreCalil - Apart from that MVC was built on top of this abstraction? That it makes your markup cleaner and easier to understand? That it allows you to leverage the platform?

Comment: One reason is DRY. You can reuse a model editor template in multiple views.

Comment: @AndreCalil - I believe you would need to justify _not_ using them, if one has already decided to use the MVC framework.

Comment: It's for security reasons also. It automatically encodes the content and doesn't allow to submit dangerous content.

Comment: @AndreCalil It's a pretty fundamental part of the framework which includes things like model binding your fields against previous inputs. Yes you can use just the backend half of MVC (routing, controllers etc) but if you aren't also using the form helpers you're losing out on half of the reason to use ASP MVC in the first place. Surely the thing that needs justification should be not using them.

Comment: I personally see it as an extra step in creating a form.  I already know how to do what I need to do in html, learning how to do it using an abstraction of that is just an unnecessary step.  Regardless, there is a bug here that is in need of discovering.

Comment: @Oded *Markup cleaner and easier to understand* is a good point. However, when it comes to markup, I believe that the most you can control its creation, the better it will perform (in many ways). Also, I believe that these abstractions lead developers to a misunderstanding of the standards. Take this question for example: I believe that a developer that always uses `BeginForm` might not now how to write a `<form>` properly.

Comment: @Chao One can perfectly use model binding without using helpers, that's not a reason, IMO.

Comment: @AndreCalil I agree you can (and said that you can just use the backend). My point was that in a framework designed around using the two together cutting out half of the design of the framework is what needs justification.

Comment: Actually, when you all say that "if you are using MVC, you should use it" you are forgeting that **MVC** and **Razor** are things apart. Razor is a view engine for MVC, and HTML Helpers are, well, *helpers* built on *the top of Razor*, not on the top of MVC. One can perfectly use ASP.NET MVC without using helpers.

Comment: @AndreCalil also the idea of " I believe that a developer that always uses BeginForm might not now how to write a `<form>` properly" doesn't make sense. Would you rather a developer mixes two different ways of writing forms just to prove that they can?

Comment: @AndreCalil That's something which will always be the case with a higher-level abstraction.  We've moved from punch cards to C# and that's happened because people have implemented tiny abstractions here and there.  The helpers aren't perfect but they're pretty reasonable.  The strongly-typed helpers are certainly a step above `Html.BeginForm()` but you could always implement that if you really wanted to.  Couple that with enabling view compilation and their value increases an awful lot.

Comment: @JohnH They are *reasonable*, I agree. I wouldn't advice someone not to use helpers, for sure, but I simply don't see a strong reason to keep repeating *you should use it*. About abstractions, well, that's a much deeper subject. I see your point, anyway.

Comment: @AndreCalil You don't think using strongly-typed HTML helpers coupled with view compilation is enough to say they should be used?  I'd strongly disagree there.  Having compile-time checks on your presentation layer is vastly superior to manually entering HTML with no checking at all.

Comment: @JohnH I'm sorry, but what do you mean with "strongly-typed HTML"? If you're talking about `EditorFor` and other `*For` controls, well, they simply don't provide enough compile time checking. In fact, about compile checking, they are as strong as plain HTML.

Comment: @AndreCalil How is `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)` only as strong as `<input id="@Model.Name" type="textbox" value="@Model.Name" />`?  The compiler will instantly tell you if you mess up.  You don't have to worry about forgetting an attribute or mistyping anything - it's guaranteed to do the same thing every time.  On top of that, the helpers will emit unobtrusive validation without you needing to manually type it yourself.

Comment: @JohnH Using Helpers does not ensure a error-free markup, I simply don't agree with this point also. So far, readability is the strongest point, IMO.

Comment: @AndreCalil It doesn't guarantee error-free markup, no, but it does take it a step closer.  You only have to look around at the questions that are asked on SO to see people who forget attributes, mistype them or even create invalid markup by mistake.  There are lots of questions from people who have created invalid markup and not had the outcome they were hoping for.  The helpers save time by providing you compiler checks up front.  Having some extra guarantees is better than having none, but I'll leave it there as this is getting quite long.  Nice talking to you all the same.

Comment: It seems a silly argument. I'm surprised that the thread is going on as long as it is. Almost every MVC framework, including rails, has the concept of HTML helpers. If you're not using them you're not taking advantage of all the tools available.

There's no reason for someone not to abstract away messy makeup, especially if they want to be able to make large system-wide changes later (like changing all text boxes). HTML Helpers - not the implementation but the general concept - are fundamental to being DRY.

Comment: Helpers are NOT on top of Razor. They are on top of MVC. You can acheive the same thing as EditorFor with HTML. It is NOT true that you HAVE to use EditorFor to make This or That work, however, as their name states, they are there to help you. They will generate that long complicated HTML that will suite your situation instead of having to figure it out on your own. EditorFor in actually just a conditional templated partial view that will pick the right template based on the data type it is provided. It's just a html element with a bunch of IF THIS, ADD THIS ATTRIBUTE.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using Asp.net mvc 3 helpers to build your forms instead of regular html tags, and build your form based on the Model. This also encodes your form input and allows you to verify AntiFrogery token:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("actionhere", ..other arguments))
{
    @Html.DropDownFor(x => x.ModelProperty, Model.List);
}
```